# Check if link has already been tweeted in PHP

Tags: php, twitter

I am running an incentive based referral site, and one of the requirements is for a user to tweet their referral link. In the "steps" on the user status page, once their link has been tweeted, I want the line saying "Tweet your link" to either disappear, or have a strike-through, to show it's been completed.

So - is there any way of checking to see if the link has been tweeted, and parse different text/style for that line?

Each referral link is unique, so can only be tweeted by that person.

Comment: -1 http://www.emilvikstrom.se/whyidownvote.html

Answer (score 5):

It's all in [the twitter API documentation](http://dev.twitter.com/), which you should read before posting.

Make a request to `http://urls.api.twitter.com/1/urls/count.json?url=` with the url-encoded URI you want to check the tweet count for.